# Liferay theme reset to default

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-ide

I don't know if I'm the only one to have this problem, I'm developing a liferay theme using the plugin sdk and eclipse. I have a theme based on classic, when I turn off eclipse and turn on again I found that all changes on custom.css are gone and reset to default classic theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this was my fault I was making changes on docroot/custom.css directly, I should put the on  _diff/.

Answer (score 3):

You have to done your custom css in _diff/css/custom.css ok

when you create the theme your _diff folder is empty so you just take all css folder, template folder, js folder and images folder form classic theme and place in _diff folder then modify in _diff/css/custom.css file

Have look into following site for more info about liferay [Liferay Savvy](http://www.liferaysavvy.com)